# Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V1.PowerBIClient..ctor(Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClientCredentials, System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler[])'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

While integrating Power bi in mvc(.net frame work 4.6.2)

getting  below error.

Method not found: `Void Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V1.PowerBIClient..ctor(Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClientCredentials, System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler[])`.

at

```
var credentials = new TokenCredentials(accessKey, "AppKey");

var client = new PowerBIClient(credentials)
{
    BaseUri = new Uri(apiUrl)
};
```

installed

Microsoft.PowerBI.Core 1.1.6.17045

Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime

Microsoft.PowerBI.Api 1.1.6.17045

stacktrace:

at DSLUI.Controllers.ReportsController.Index() in E:\DM\DSLServices\DSLUI\Controllers\ReportsController.cs:line 53
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

any help please..

Comment: Did you read the documentation or browse the definition of class `PowerBIClient` to see what parameters are being expected by it constructor?

Comment: yes read doc and sample code download from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/power-bi-embedded/power-bi-embedded-get-started-sample. and its working fine.in my case i have a project having .net framework 4.0 i updated 4.6.2 and added above dlls, 0 build errors.but at runtime im getting this exception.

Comment: Oh.. Ok.. Got it... Are getting error at line `var client = new PowerBIClient(credentials)` ?? Can you provide bit more information on it ?

Comment: while debugging when the cursor reaching this place an exception got raised in at catch block.the cursor not even execute  the line var client = new PowerBIClient(credentials)

Answer (score 2):

Issue with the System.Net.Http.dll referance, i found this is old version 2.x.x.x

Upgrade to 4.0.0.0, then it should be as below in web.config

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Then i faced another issue

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

for this add

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2">
  <assemblies>     
    <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />   
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: Deleted the reference altogether to make it work :) thanks a lot for your remark, I would never be able to get it on my own.

Comment: Bizarre that this fixes the problem, I had the same issue with a completely different library but the same sort of ctor error.